# Cannot update primary key field value in propel

Tags: php, mysql, propel

I am trying to update a field value of a row item which is a primary key field. Table structure is as follows.

```
mysql> desc sms_service_settings;
+-----------------------------+------------------------------+------+-----+-----------+-------+
| Field                       | Type                         | Null | Key | Default  
+-----------------------------+------------------------------+------+-----+--------
| customer_id                 | int(11) unsigned             | NO   | PRI | NULL 
| daily_limit                 | decimal(8,2)                 | YES  |     | NULL 
| account_type                | enum('Post-paid','Pre-paid') | NO   |     | Post-paid
| credit_amount               | double(8,4)                  | YES  |     | NULL 
+-----------------------------+------------------------------+------+-----+--------
```

Schema definition for table is as follows

```
<table name="sms_service_settings" idMethod="native" phpName="SmsServiceSettings">
    <column name="customer_id" phpName="CustomerId" type="BIGINT" primaryKey="true" required="true" defaultValue="0"/>
    <column name="daily_limit" phpName="DailyLimit" type="DECIMAL" size="8" scale="2"/>
    <column name="account_type" phpName="AccountType" type="VARCHAR" sqlType="enum('Post-paid','Pre-paid')"  size="15" defaultValue="Post-paid"/>
    <vendor type="mysql">
      <parameter name="Engine" value="MyISAM"/>
    </vendor>
  </table>
```

My propel code is as follows.

```
$sms_service = SmsServiceSettingsQuery::create()
                    ->findPK($original_customer_id);
$sms_service->setCustomerId($new_customer_id);
$sms_service->save();
```

This nothing return any error. But customer_id is not updated. Can someone please help.

Comment: Check if it is referenced by another table as a foreign key. Also it would be very helpful if you'd show us the entire SQL query

Comment: `$new_customer_id` may be exists in the another row

Comment: @MisirJafarov No. New customer id is not exist in the table.

Comment: @Arkoudinos there is no any foreign key relation for this fields in table.

Comment: @GayanFernando can you check for mysql errors with `mysqli_error()` (or using pdo)?

Comment: or run this command on phpmyadmin (or on mysql cli) to get what's the problem?

Comment: Try to find the actual query, copy-paste in on MySQL console, run it, and check what it gives back. This will help you a lot to track down the issue.